# Passing js callback function as parameter to Java addJavascriptInterface

Tags: javascript, android, crosswalk

Is it possible for arbitrary functional objects in js to be passed to Java side, so java can call that js object? (a callback)

for example, (access is a function that already registered to call a Java function)

```
access(function(blabla){
    ...
});
```

Are there any great techniques that can deal with anonymous callback function in java?

Comment: `var` cannot be passed. Check for primitive types

Comment: what`s mean, @NikolaDespotoski ? is there some bypass style?

Comment: Try to pass data using JSON string instead returning arbitrary var object....

Comment: So, js user can`t use closure concept for custom js ?

Answer (score 4):

You just need some sort of key to reference your individual callback anonymous function. I think this is how jsonp is used sometimes too.

Javascript:

```
var callbacks = [];
function registerCallback(callback)
{
   callbacks.push(callback);
   return callbacks.length - 1;
}

function getCallback(index)
{
   var callback = callbacks[index];
   callbacks[index] = null;

   TryGCCallbacks();

   return callbacks;
}

//The array index positions must be preserved, but when it's empty, we should restart the array so it doesn't grow forever
function TryGCCallbacks()
{
   var isCallbackRemaining = false;
   for (var i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++)
   {
      if (callbacks[i] == null) {
         continue;
      }

      isCallbackRemaining = true;
      break;
   }
   if (isCallbackRemaining == false)
   {
      callbacks = []; //reset
   }
}
```

Java:

```
@org.xwalk.core.JavascriptInterface
public String TestCallback(String someData, String onSuccess, String onError){
   xwalk.evaluateJavascript("getCallback(" + onSuccess + ")('success');", null);
}
```

Using this from Javascript:

```
var onSuccess = registerCallback(function(r) {
   console.log(r);
});

TestCallback('lalala', onSuccess, null);
```

Comment: This is something that should be built into XWalk somehow. This is very handy.

Comment: Java : xwalk.post(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    
                    xwalk.evaluateJavascript("(function(){ AndroidStatic.callBack(" + "\"" + result + "\"" + "); })();", null);
                }
            });

Comment: Javascript : var AndroidStatic = {
   callBack: function (result) {
      //alert(result);
      console.log(result);
   }
};